# Validate Crontab with Github Action

Tags: ubuntu, cron, github-actions

I have a crontab like:

```
46 1 * * * curl -Ssi -X POST https://example.com/...
0 1 1 * * curl -Ssi -X POST https://example.com/... 
...
```

I want to validate it with github-action. Is it possible?

Tried it like:

```
name: Main
on: [push]

env:
  CRONTAB_FILE : './crontab'

jobs:
  build_test:
    name: Check Crontab file
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: 'run crontab command from file'
        run : crontab < $CRONTAB_FILE
```

Is it enough?

Comment: Please try it  and report back if there's a specific problem :)

Comment: @rethab, it works. I wonder whether there is better way or not.